# ContentFlow usage using Java, PrimeFaces, and jsf

Tags: database, servlets, jsf-2, primefaces, arrays

I'm using ContentFlow (http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) to display images from a database using Java, PrimeFaces, and jsf. I'm using an image servlet to help render my image byte array.

This is successful upon initial page load with my list of images, but after my list of images changes (using results from a datatable filter) I can't find a way to reload/refresh the ContentFlow with the new list of images.

This refresh works successfully without the ContentFlow implemented, but it appears to either be doing something behind the scenes within the Javascript that breaks this or it's not playing well with the image servlet (sometimes I get an IllegalStateException). I'm having alot of trouble finding anyone out there to help with this.

Here's my stacktrace...

```
Error Rendering View[/index.xhtml]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2636) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2375) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:841) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.getSession(ExternalContextWrapper.java:396) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_32]
```

ImgServlet.java

```
/**
   * Servlet implementation class ImgServlet
   */
    @WebServlet(name = "ImgServlet", urlPatterns = {"/ImgServlet/*"})
    public class ImgServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    Screenshot model;
        @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "primary")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf; 

    public ImgServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        ServletContext sc = getServletContext();

        String classString = "Screenshot";
        String idString = request.getParameter("id");

        if (classString == null || classString.isEmpty() || idString == null || idString.isEmpty()) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

        Long id = Long.parseLong(idString.trim());
        PhotoInterface entry = null;

        EntityManager em = null;

        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
        } catch (Throwable e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 

        try {
            entry = em.find(Screenshot.class, id);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Log.log(ex.getMessage());
        }

        if (entry == null) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
            return;
        }

        ServletOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            response.reset();

             // It works ok without setting any of these...
            //response.setContentType(image.getContentType());
            //response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(image.getLength()));
            //response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + image.getName() + "\"");
            response.setContentType("image/png");

            out = response.getOutputStream();

            if (entry.getPng() != null && entry.getPng().length != 0) {
                out.write(entry.getPng());
                getServletContext().log("Found png!!");
            }
            else 
                getServletContext().log("png is NULL!!!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            getServletContext().log("Error finding png!!!");
        } finally {
            close(out);
        }

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private static void close(Closeable resource) {
        if (resource != null) {
            try {
                resource.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Do your thing with the exception. Print it, log it or mail it.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ContentFlow Javascript file to make the ContentFlow can be viewed at http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/download.php Not enough space to include it here.

This bit of xhtml code will work after getting datatable selection list. Also, tried with filtered datatable filtered results list. The ContentFlow divs aren't implemented here...

```
<p:commandButton id="viewDetails" value="View Selected Screenshots" icon="ui-icon-search"  
                             update=":form:imgBlock"/> 

          <p:outputPanel id="imgBlock" layout="block"> 
             <a4j:repeat var="img" value="#{screenshotListProducer.selectedScreenshots}">
               <img src="ImgServlet?id=#{img.id}" title="#{img.time}"/>
             </a4j:repeat>
          </p:outputPanel>
```

This bit of xhtml code doesn't work after encapsulating with the ContentFlow divs. Something must be happening behind the scenes that I just don't understand....

```
<p:commandButton id="viewDetails" value="View Selected Screenshots" icon="ui-icon-search"  
                             update=":form:imgBlock"/> 

          <p:outputPanel id="imgBlock" layout="block"> 
           <div class="ContentFlow" id="ContentFlow">
            <div class="flow">
             <a4j:repeat var="img" value="#{screenshotListProducer.selectedScreenshots}">
              <div class="item">
               <img src="ImgServlet?id=#{img.id}" title="#{img.time}"/>
              </div>
             </a4j:repeat>
            </div>
           </div>
          </p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: can you post a bit of code and the stacktrace of that exception?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. Created a custom Javascript function that refreshed the ContentFlow successfully.